# How can I change spelling language in indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am using Indesign 14.0.2 and I am translating a document from Swedish to English. When I re-saved the document, the only dictionary available is the Swedish one:

[image]

So I created a document from scratch, and copied all the elements into this new document. This makes all the dictionaries available:

[image]

but even though I choose an English dictionary like so:

[image]

Swedish is still the language used for spell-checking:

[image]

What should I do to make the change of dictionary stick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must change the text spelling language from the **Character Panel** before activating the Check-spelling, or set the paragraph style spelling language if the text is in a paragraph style.

[image]

Then when you open the Check-Spelling panel the spelling language will be the one chosen for the text.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH for this answer! I just had similar issue and this fixed it.
Was very frustrating.